# Take a screenshot and print it in Java

Tags: java, printing, installation, screenshot, interactive

I am in need of help. I'm not a very proficient coder, so i'll ask directly.

I am looking to create a script that would be initiated through the pressing of a keyboard button. It would then wait randomly between 10 to 30 seconds and then take a screenshot. The screenshot would be then added to the print queue and printed with a printer.

I am aware of two scripts which do two steps of this, but unsure how to connect them to a seamless thing ( along with a delay mechanism, which is important, also would be good to have a 5 second period between possible initiations of the script so you can't make 50 prints in the queue when you mash the button and wreck the system )

( for information it would be taking screenshots of the output of an interactive system working with generative stuff and video feed, im not yet sure on the software i will use for that maybe vvvv )

Take screenshot

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class screen2image
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File("screenShot.jpg"));
    }
}
```

// print image

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("YOurImageFileName.PNG");
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fin, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, null);
job.print(doc, pras);
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this. It would be great for my project.

Comment: For a delay mechanism you could run the program in a loop with a thread.sleep. Take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html